# How to randomize slider images in foreach loop in Razor Syntax?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, foreach

I have this slider inside a Razor Syntax foreach loop, there are about 20 images, I only want to take 5 out of the 20 images, and randomize every set of 5 images, below is the code, any help would be appreciated.

```
@foreach (var data in Model.BeaconsOfHope.Take(5))
{
  <div class="swiper-slide">
    <img class="pull-left" src="@data.image" />
    <div class="pull-left donor-info">
      <span class="name" style="font-weight:bold;">@data.name</span>
      @*<span class="rank">@data.rank</span>*@
      <span class="country">@data.country</span>
    </div>
  </div>
}
```

Comment: What does it mean "doesn't like "Random()" part"? In LINQ there is no Random method, is it your extension method? If not, check e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449452/linq-order-by-random how to shuffle a collection. But I think that you want also to change the order of the methods call, because now it will take first 5 images and shuffle them. Don't you want to shuffle images first and then select first 5 images?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want, shuffle images first and then select first 5 images.

Comment: Then you have to switch the method calls `Model.BeaconsOfHope.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(5)`

Answer (score 1):

Change first line to:

@foreach (var data in Model.BeaconsOfHope.orderby(x=>Guid.NewGuid()).Take(5))

Comment: How is this different than the answer provided by Jookyn in the comments?

Comment: I want to also mention that all lowercase "orderby" threw an error for me. I followed the casing from Lukas and that worked properly for me.