# Add 5 random cards to listbox, listbox show SAME cards

Tags: c#, listbox

I have a button on my windows form which add five random cards to my list.
The random cards are displayed in a listbox.
When I first press the button, the listbox show 5 random cards.
When I press the button again, the listbox shows the same 5 random cards 3 times now.
Instead of 10 random cards.
Is there anyway to get rid of this problem?

```
 private void RandomButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i = i + 1)
            fiveRandomCards.Add(new Card((Symbool)random.Next(1, 4), (Waarde)random.Next(1, 14)));
        foreach (Card card in fiveRandomCards)
            CardsLB.Items.Add(card.name);                
    }
```

Comment: Don't create a new `Random` object every time you click the button. Create a class field for it and instantiate it when the form is created.

Comment: Off topic: please try to use English instead of your native language when naming variables, methods etc. You and other developers will find it very useful, believe me

Comment: start with a full deck of cards, remove 5 and place them in the list - now you cant reselect them

Comment: You are not removing items from list. Note that to actually write what you described you need to shuffle full list of cards and take first five. Search for "c# randomize list".

Answer (score 0):

I actually like this approach ***for small collections***

[linq: order by random](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449452/linq-order-by-random/9449476#9449476)

pseudo code

```
ICollection<int> coll = new List<int>() {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14};
ICollection<int> randomFiveItems = coll.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(5);
```

Then bind randomFiveItems  that do your control

```
KaartenLB.DataSource = randomFiveItems;
```

Klar für mich

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my problem, it is quite simple.
I have 2 lists in my program: 
The first list is "deck", which already holds 52 cards, those are generated in my Form1_load method.
The second  list is "fiveRandomCards".
On my windows form i have a button.
When I click on this button it adds 5 radom cards from my deck list to the fiveRandomCards list.
I added a clear() method to my listbox so the items in the listbox won't stack.

Keep in mind, in my Card class, I uses 2 enums: Symbol -> diamonds, clubs, hearts and spades.
                                                Value -> from 1 to 13.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<Card> deck = new List<Card>(); //allready has 52 cards in it.
    List<Card> fiveRandomCards = new List<Card>(); 
    Random random = new Random();

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int symbol = 1; symbol < 5; symbol = symbol + 1)
            {
                for (int value = 1; value < 14; value = value + 1)
                    deck.Add(new Card((Symbol)symbol, (Value)value));
            }
        }
    private void RandomButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i = i + 1)
            fiveRandomCards.Add(deck[random.Next(0, deck.Count)]); 
        CardsLB.Items.Clear();
        foreach (Card card in fiveRandomCards)
            CardsLB.Items.Add(card.name);                
    }
}
```