# Get randomically or row from a table

Tags: sql, t-sql, random

I need you help...for a little problem.
I have a java service that should access in a table and **get a random  row from table**.

My table is simply: it contains only two cols:

```
"Id"        INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL Primary Key
"Datas"     Varchar(64)       NOT NULL
```

Values *Id* is an progressive number, so you should think it could be enough to create a random number and get the row where id=randomic_number.

But I have lots of gap in table. So for example, a sample of table could be this:

```
  ID    Datas
  1     Row1
  2     Row2
  3     Row3
  8     Row4
 10     Row5
 25     Row6
639     Row7
```

Is there a very stylish way to get one row randomly? No condition must be...only random!
I use sql srv 2000.

I would avoid to to...

```
select *
```

and then cycling the entire Resultset using a random number...because it can contain a very large number of rows....

Comment: see http://www.titov.net/2005/09/21/do-not-use-order-by-rand-or-how-to-get-random-rows-from-table/

Comment: What database are you using? I assume MSSQL (due to the `IDENTITY` keyword)?

Comment: Alright. Thanks for clarifying. I added the `tsql` tag to reflect this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to request a random row in SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412/how-to-request-a-random-row-in-sql)

Comment: EXHUMA!!! FANTASTIC!!!

SELECT TOP 1 column FROM table
ORDER BY NEWID()

THANK you VERY MUCH!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do something along the lines of:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM mytable ORDER BY newid()
```

Note: this is a duplicate of [#52964](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52964/sql-server-random-sort) which is in turn a duplicate of [#19412](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412/how-to-request-a-random-row-in-sql)

Comment: In SQL, the `rand` function will generate one random value for the statement and apply that one value to every row returned.

Comment: Great answer, I just tried it on PostgreSQL and it works. Using the database to return the random row is the best option as doing it in java on the client will not be nearly as elegant or efficient

Comment: If performance matters then this will cause an end-to-end scan of the entire table. There are ways to avoid it, eg. see [Limiting Result Sets by Using TABLESAMPLE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189108(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: RANDOM() is not a valid function in sql serv2000....
I tried with 

SELECT Top 1 * FROM MyTable ORDER BY RAND()

but it's not randomic! It return always the same row... :(

Comment: @RemusRusanu I thought `TABLESAMPLE` is not truly random. But my experience with it is flaky. It really depends on your use-case. As far as I remember, if you want "truly" random results, you should use `NEWID()` instead of `TABLESAMPLE`. Correct me if I'm wrong...

Comment: @user3914783 Yes. My bad. I fixed it. The reason here is that `RAND()`   is evaluated before the query is executed. Essentially, ending up with a query like `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY 3453` (where 3453 is the random number).

Comment: `Newid` is, indeed, the way to go in SQL. I prefer `checksum(newid())`, as that further randomizes however sequential a series of guids might be.

Comment: @PhilipKelley How does `checksum` further randomise this? To my knowledge `checksum` is a -- *ducks* -- hashing function (i.e. deterministic). So the same ID will always return the same result. I don't see how that would aid in randomisation.

Comment: Indeed `TABLESAMPLE` is not completely random, as the unit of selection is page not a row. But if you have significant data size then the trade off is necessary. One can combine TABLESAMPLE with top(1) ... order by newid() to get 'quite random' w/o paying the penalty of large data scans. If the table is small then why bother, indeed...

Comment: @PhilipKelley `newid()` guids have no 'sequentialness' whatsoever. for all purposes, bare crypto, they are as random as it gets.

Comment: EXHUMA!!! FANTASTIC!!! SELECT TOP 1 column FROM table ORDER BY NEWID() THANK you VERY MUCH!!!

Comment: I've never been able to track down the actual algorithm for generating a guid (anyone got a link?) but I do know they are based on internal time and "NIC card", or some such. They are not random in the true sense, though they are certainly random enough for things like this. (And I got a bit confused with the more recent "sequential guid" function.) If sequential, checksum would at least de-sequentialize them, since it would be a hash on different values.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to get the last id in the table like so

```
SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM table_name ORDER BY Id DESC
```

then assuming this is stored in the `maxId` variable, you could generate a random number `index` between `1` and `maxId` and do :

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM table_name WHERE Id > index
```

And that's it

Comment: Not randomic at all if I have a big gap.
For example: I have the following ID: 1,2,3,650,651,652,etc...

Randomic numbers beetween 4 and 649...will return me always the same row (n° 650)...