# How to use LIMIT keyword in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, limit

I have found a way to select random rows from a table in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412/how-to-request-a-random-row-in-sql). A suggestion is to use the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM employee ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

But when I run this query in MS SQL 2005, I get the following error message

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'LIMIT'.
```

Can anyone tell me where am I wrong? Doesn't MS SQL support LIMIT? If so, then how can I do this?

Comment: ORDER BY rand() will *not* do what you expect it to, as proven by SELECT *, rand() FROM employee ORDER BY RAND(). Instead, use ORDER BY newid().

Answer (score 50):

If you take a look at the SELECT statement in SQL Server Books Online, then you'll see that you can limit the resultset by using the TOP keyword.

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM employee
```

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Employee ORDER BY newid()
```

You have to use newid() for it to be evaluated once per row.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this fairly simple one (SQL2005) to limit the number of rows returned, which will work with a value provided by a stored procedure parameter as well.

```
DECLARE @Limit int
SET @Limit = 10
SELECT TOP (@Limit) Col1, Col2 FROM SomeTable
```