# Syntax error near 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select

What's wrong with the following statement? I'm using SQL Server 2008.

```
use Demo;

SELECT * FROM users
limit 0 , 30
```

I got:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near '0'.
```

That's really weird. I tried Google but didn't find much info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`LIMIT` is a MySQL keyword. Use the `TOP` or `ROWCOUNT` keywords in MS SQL Server.

Note that `TOP` can accept a variable, e.g. `SELECT TOP( @NumberOfRows ) * FROM Foo;`

See: [How to use LIMIT keyword in SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455008/how-to-use-limit-keyword-in-sql-server-2005) (also valid for 2008)

Depending on how `LIMIT` is used, there **is** an important difference between `LIMIT` and `TOP` ([ranges/pages of data](http://www.mysqlfaqs.net/mysql-faqs/SQL-Statements/Select-Statement/How-to-use-LIMIT-clause-in-MySQL) versus just capping the number of results). In that case, the MS SQL syntax is more verbose; usually the ROW_NUMBER() function does the trick combined with some simple logic to calculate the values which are valid for the desired page.

### Simple Range Selection Example

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY SomeColumn ASC ) AS RowNumber, 
        AnotherColumn 
    FROM dbo.MyTable
) Q

WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN 20 AND 30; -- these integers can be variables
```

Comment: [SQL Server 2012 has a less verbose syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5525978/73226)

Answer (score 4):

```
select top 30 * from users
```

SQL Server uses *that* syntax rather than the `limit` form.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server doesn't support the `limit` clause (that is the MySQL and PostgreSQL syntax). You should use `top` like this:

```
select top 30 * from users
```