# Using PHP PDO with MSSQL database to fetch records for given limit

Tags: php, pdo

I am using MSSQL database with PHP. For database connection i am using PDO connection.
My all operations are working fine like SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE.

I am getting issue while fetching data for a given limit, i have searched almost all the examples given on web and even the solutions given on stackoverflow on the post

[How to apply bindValue method in LIMIT clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269840/php-pdo-bindvalue-in-limit)

I have also find some examples using LIMIT and OFFSET but nothing works for me.

I have also used the below code given on stackoverflow in a post

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tblfish LIMIT %d,%d";
$sql = sprintf($sql, 0, 10);
$statement = $dbcon->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
```

And also

```
$fetchPictures = $dbcon->prepare("select * from tblfish where IDFishUserId = :user ORDER BY user_id ASC LIMIT :skip, :max");
$dbcon->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, FALSE);
$fetchPictures->bindValue(':user', $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

$fetchPictures->bindValue(':skip', 0, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$fetchPictures->bindValue(':max', 10, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$fetchPictures->execute() or die(print_r($fetchPictures->errorInfo()));
```

But nothing works.

Can anybody please help, is there any issue with my implementations.

Thanks

Comment: Each DBMS vendor implements its own SQL dialect. You can't use MySQL's `LIMIT` keyword in SQL Server, just like you can't use Java functions in your PHP code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use LIMIT keyword in SQL Server 2005?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455008/how-to-use-limit-keyword-in-sql-server-2005)

Comment: Thanks @ÁlvaroG.Vicario for your reply, Actually i have to use paging for my records, so can you please suggest me what would be the better idea for that.

Comment: @Dinesh Go look at the link he provided, it shows you how to do paging in MSSQL without using the LIMIT keyword.