# Select random line in SQL database

Tags: php, sql, mysql, select, random

I would like to select a random line in my database. I saw this solution on a website:

```
SELECT column FROM table
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

This SQL query run but someone said me that it was a non performant query. Is there another solution ?

Thx

Comment: For future reference: RAND() only works on mysql.

Answer (score 3):

It is. You have to count rows number with

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table`;
```

After this with php function mt_rand() get the random from 1 to $count and get it with query:

```
SELECT `column` FROM `table` LIMIT $rand, 1
```

Comment: Ok, Thanks :) Another question, unrelated development, I'm French and I would like to know if my English is correct, comprehensible ?

Comment: oops, in some reason i thought you asked about `mysql`. Did you? :-S

Comment: For english ? No, not about mysql.

Comment: Then what dbms did you talk about at the initial question? `Microsoft SQL Server`?

Comment: Ohh the initial question, yes there was MySQL ^^

Comment: @Jensen: I´m Argentinian and speak Spanish, but understand your English perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot more discussion of this subject, including performance implications and strategies for different DBMSs, in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412/how-to-request-a-random-row-in-sql).

Comment: All the answers from that topic can be separated into 2 categories. 1. **slow** with using of RAND() (or DBMS-specific synonym) or 2. the calculating some random `id` in the range [1, id] and finding value that >= of that. and this solution gives us irregular randomize coverage (Ex: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1000000000000. In this case in 99.99% of cases you will get the latest row). This is **not true uniform random**

Comment: I think this is a matter of TANSTAAFL. Approaches like TABLESAMPLE clearly trade randomness for speed (and are vendor-specific). If you want to go down the rabbit-hole of seeking true randomness, you're adding a theoretical math problem to an implementation challenge. 

You could add a trigger that populates a column with a pseudo-random number on insert, "pre-slicing" your large table into manageable shards, then select a row, rand() limit 1, from one shard. So, pre-calculating some of the "fake" randomness. I agree that all these approaches involve compromise between purity and practicality.