# random select from table

Tags: php, mysql, random

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to request a random row in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412/how-to-request-a-random-row-in-sql)

```
           I have table:
           name,age,school
           jane,15,zu
           peter,16,zu
           john,15,stu
           Tomas,15,kul
           viera,17,stu
           tibor15,zu
```

I want select from this table 1 person (randomly) per school

Comment: dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412/how-to-request-a-random-row-in-sql

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table  group by school order by rand()
```

Comment: Not working,still the same record per school

Comment: I  removed limit pls check again

Comment: Still not working for me.After run this query:order of records are not the same,but person is still same:

Comment: for example:1)peter,16,zu;john,15,stu;Tomas,15,kul 2)john,15,stu;peter,16,zu;Tomas,15,kul

Comment: i want this:1)peter,16,zu;john,15,stu;Tomas,15,kul 2)jane,16,zu;viera,15,stu;tomas,15,kul

Comment: select * from table  group by school, person order by rand()

Comment: why i must group person? ...result give me more unneeded records.

Comment: it is not possible using SQL,i think. I try resolve it with array in PHP

Answer (score 0):

It's terribly innefficient since it's ORDERing the entire table randomly, and then GROUPing on a potentially huge unindexed temporary table, but this works.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
     SELECT * 
     FROM  my_table 
     ORDER BY RAND()
     )a
GROUP BY school
```

It would likely be more wise to break it down.

1. One query to retrieve a list of
   schools.
2. For each school, one     query to get a random student for     that school.

See [this post](http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/) for some slick tricks on how to get single random values efficiently.

Comment: Works perfectly.Tthat is exactly what i looking for. Thank you Riedsio

Answer (score -2):

If you are using php (as the tag suggests), run `SELECT * FROM table;` then generate a random number based on the number of results in the query. For example:

```
i = floor(random()*query.length);
```

Then seek to the record indicated `seek(i)` and viola, you have a random entry =)

You'll have to use your own knowledge/documentation for the exact syntax, I haven't touched PHP in a while, but the logic is sound.

Gary

Comment: Not very useful when there's more than a few rows in the database...

Comment: As @A said, this is a terrible idea. On large tables this will be very slow, and create unneeded load on the database.