# MySQL: How to retrieve a random row or multiple random rows?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database table that stores the URLs of photos. I need to pull 5 random records from the database of a particular type. I can pull 5 records like this:

```
SELECT Photos.* 
FROM Photos 
WHERE Photos.Type_ID = 4 
LIMIT 5
```

Now I need help trying to figure out how to pull different records every time. How can I retrieve random rows from this result set?

Comment: Dup of [What is the best way to request a random row in pure SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19412/90527)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `ORDER BY RAND()` to get random rows in your query.

Comment: You've just called the wrath of SQL's upon you.

Comment: It's actually can be very slow on large data-sets.

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT Photos.* 
FROM Photos 
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 2):

Google points to this detailed page. Looks like it works. I am sure it can't ensure **distinct record each time**, but worth trying. http://akinas.com/pages/en/blog/mysql_random_row/