# SQL pulling random images from database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, image, random

I know close to zero when it comes to SQL.

I've been looking in the code of a theme I have and it's pulling the images in order

```
$get_imgs = mysql_query("SELECT file FROM uploaded_images ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, $results");
```

How can I change the order to random?

Would I just change the ORDER to RANDOM?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL: How to retrieve a random row or multiple random rows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586858/mysql-how-to-retrieve-a-random-row-or-multiple-random-rows)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$get_imgs = mysql_query("SELECT file FROM uploaded_images ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0, $results");
```

Comment: Thanks I see what you did there I was close in guessing, thanks again works fine.