# Mysql 1 Random Row

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to request a random row in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412/how-to-request-a-random-row-in-sql)

Is this the correct way to do this?

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM gameids ORDER BY timestamp RAND LIMIT 1';
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Incorrect. You cant order by a column (afaik) if you want it to randomize.

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM gameids ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1';
```

Comment: Won't work with `rand` - `rand()` is a function.

Comment: @Piskvor: I rewrote my answer.

Comment: +1 for being about 30 seconds faster at typing!

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to tell it which column to randomise, but you do need `()` after `RAND` because it is a function.

```
SELECT
  * 
FROM
  gameids 
ORDER BY 
  RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 2):

RAND is a function and its not effective in big tables, because it does not use indexes.

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM gameids ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1';
```

One possible solution is to add column called `random` and on every record generate random number for it, then when you are querying the database, order by this column and you'll get pseudo-random but this time using the indexes.

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM gameids ORDER BY timestamp, random LIMIT 1';
```

Edit:
You can also make `RAND()` more "flexible" by applying some expression like this `RAND() * MAX(numeric_column_name)`

If you are interested in optimizations, take a look at this blog post: http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/

@Marwelln is correct.

Comment: Well this is a very very big database is there a way to get the total rows, and then generate a random number to sort by?

Comment: Is it innnoDB or MyISAM? What type is your primary key? Do you have columns with numeric data only?