# Laravel get a random user with where clause

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

My table schema is a id field, name field and a friends id field.

Every user must have a maximum of 2 friends. When a new user is created and event is fired and a listener which listens to the created user event then adds a random friend to a newly created user.

```
 $randomfriend =  DB::table('users')->select('id')
                                   ->groupBy('friends_id')
                                   ->havingRAW('COUNT(*) < 2')
                                   ->inRandomOrder()->first();
```

it still returns users with maximum number of friends. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: remove groupby?

Comment: pls run `dd(DB::table('users')->select('id')
                                   ->groupBy('friends_id')
                                   ->havingRAW('COUNT(*) < 2')
                                   ->inRandomOrder()->toSql());` and print the output so we can see the query

Comment: How are you storing the friends relationship?

Comment: @Ross Wilson am not using eloquent as that's part of the requirements.

Comment: Sorry, poor choice of words. How do you tell if a user has friends i.e. is it through a pivot table, column(s) on the users table etc? I've noticed you have a `friends_id` column but it's not clear how you're using it as you've said a user can have 2 friends.

Comment: Am just using one table that is user's table. I have this the DB query inside a function. If a there's a user that his ID appears twice under the friend's ID column then that user can not be returned as a result of that query

Answer (score 2):

first of all create another table for friends relations.
for selecting a random user this post can help you:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938871/mysql-1-random-row)

don't forget to put this code in while loop for checks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but then a requirement is to use a single table.

Comment: in this answer its not required to use two tables. you can use this approach with your code.