# SQL: Order by both a column and rand()?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

My table has many row that have a same column. I'll call the column "likes". If I use "order by likes", then the rows with the same "likes" will be ordered by the time they were added to the database.
I want all rows with the same "likes" to be sorted randomly. I tried "ORDER BY likes, rand()", but everything is being sorted randomly.
How can I do this?

Comment: it would help to show the table definition and the query

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to request a random row in SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412/how-to-request-a-random-row-in-sql)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you check again. Adding the clause `order by something, rand()` to one of my queries acts *exactly* as you would expect, with the only randomising happening within a `something` group.

Just be aware that using `rand()` in an `order by` clause will not scale very well as your table gets bigger.

Answer (score 0):

Im not pretty sure since i dont know the structure of your tables and i dont know the query... but try adding `GROUP BY likes` to your query

Comment: Although he wants results *grouped by* likes, `GROUP BY` would not be correct here; that gathers all similar items into a single row to show the result of aggregation functions.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you are doing it backwards (e.g., "ORDER BY RAND(), something" rather than "ORDER BY something, RAND())