# Trying to use the 'not equal to' (relational operator) in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to select random post ID's from multiple tables but assuming the user has not already viewed the post before. I have gathered all the post ID's the user has view in an array and I was hoping to use that to rule out a random post.

My thinking has brought me to a query like this but it's obviously wrong because the ID is being used twice.

```
    (SELECT id FROM table1)
UNION (SELECT id FROM table2)
WHERE id != 423812240250 
ORDER BY rand() 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Please elaborate upon _"My thinking has brought me to a query like this but it's obviously wrong because the ID is being used twice."_

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to do and what the != operator has to do with it.

Comment: if you're looking to select a random row of your table, look at this post: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412/...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412/how-to-request-a-random-row-in-sql)

Comment: `mysql not equal to` <- This query in Google search might've helped you reach the skies! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<>` for that:

```
(SELECT id FROM table1)
UNION (SELECT id FROM table2)
WHERE id <> 423812240250 
ORDER BY rand() 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: != and <> are the same, look in the manual http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html

Comment: Tiny, you should rewrite your question so that people know what you want