# Retrieve random data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to retrieve 2 random data from this list? Every time when I execute the T-sql code, it always should retrieve 2 row with different data.

```
CREATE TABLE Data
(   
    StartTime VARCHAR(5), 
    EndTime VARCHAR(5), 
)   
GO

INSERT INTO Data(StartTime,EndTime)   
SELECT '10:00','12:00' UNION ALL
SELECT '13:30','16:00' UNION ALL
SELECT '14:00','15:00' UNION ALL
GO
```

// Fullmetaloby

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412/how-to-request-a-random-row-in-sql

just give limit 2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 2 StartTime, EndTime FROM Data
ORDER BY NEWID()
```