# Randomly assign the contents of a Button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm creating a quiz for kids in WPF.

All the questions are coming from a database.

The interface has a textblock for the question and four buttons for the multiple choice answers.

How do I randomly assign the Content of the buttons so that the correct answer isn't in the same button all the time?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to request a random row in SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412/how-to-request-a-random-row-in-sql)

Comment: In short, use a random-number generator (such as the .NET Random class) to apply a random order to the set of answers, and, once ordered, assign the answers to the buttons. If you want a less-vague answer, please show us what you've got so far. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a method to shuffle the answers:

```
  List<string> Shuffle(List<string> answers)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        Dictionary<int, string> d = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        foreach (var answer in answers)
        {
            d.Add(r.Next(), answer);
        }
        return d.OrderBy(a => a.Key).Select(b => b.Value).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: Might be able to find a better shuffle algorithm, but good answer nonetheless.

Comment: @Servy, indeed it's just an idea

Answer (score 2):

Essentially you could do this by just generating a random number between 0 and 3 as your location of your correct answer.  Then display the rest of the answers in whatever order they come form the database.

To get the random number you can use:

```
var placeHolder = new Random().Next(0,3);
```