# Select random records in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to request a random row in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412/how-to-request-a-random-row-in-sql)

Hi I am trying to select random records from a oracle database. I tried using the query below:

```
select field1 
from (select field1 from table1 where field2='SAMPLE_VALUE' order by dbms_random.value) 
where rownum <2;
```

This works just fine, except that it's extremely slow and expensive.

Do we have any quicker way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You could try the SAMPLE clause:

```
select field1
from   table1 sample (1)
where  field2='SAMPLE_VALUE' and
       rownum <=1
```

However:

1. You're probably not going to get index-based access
2. there's no guarantee you'd get enough values
3. You'd probably tend to get values from the "beginning" of the table.

Comment: What if there is no record with `field2='SAMPLE_VALUE'` in the 1% ?

Comment: As I say, there's no guarantee that you'd get enough values, particularly for very selective queries. However if the DBMS_Random approach is very slow and expensive then I'd expect that to be because there are a great many records to be sorted so the chances of finding some ought to be reasonably good in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If records has some unique numeric column, I would try to compare it to randomly generated value. Something like `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE id = RANDOM_VALUE`. But some calculations may be needed to have the same range for this unique column and for random value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check execution plan.
It's probably doing a `full access` to the table, so if you can add  an index on `field2` this might make it worth for the optimizer to do an `index range scan` according to your `where clause`.
(I don't really know about field2 anything, so check it carefully)