# Randomly picking entity not yet in a join table

Tags: database, performance, optimization

This seems interesting.

Assume three tables, `users`, `items` and a join table `users_items`. The latter links `users.id`s to `items.id`s. We say that user `U` owns item `I` when there's a row in the `users_items` table that contains the pair (`U.id`, `I.id`).

Now: how would I go about randomly choosing an item that a particular user **does not yet own**?

The most feasible solution seems to be:

1. gather all item `id`s.
2. gather `id`s of items owned by user `U`.
3. remove all `id`s from step #2 from the set generated in #1
4. pick random element from the resulting set (trivial)

Is this the only sane way? Is it optimal? Let's assume this would be a heavily used feature. And the numbers of elements in each table are huge.

Any fun ideas, thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a left join to generate a list of item ids that the user does not currently own by doing :

```
SELECT i.id
FROM items i 
LEFT JOIN users_items ui ON ( i.id = ui.item_id AND ui.users_id = 2 )
WHERE ui.item_id IS NULL;
```

From here, you can randomly select one of the elements from the result set.

Comment: But that would only join with the items that user 2 owns. For one what if user 2 is the one querying this? For another this would not return all the items that the user doesn't have. This would only work if the querying user owns what user 2 does not and vis versa.

Comment: The [left join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Left_outer_join) allows you to match each record in the items table ( the left table ) with rows from the users_items ( right table ), even if a matching record does not exist in the right table.By adding the WHERE ui.item_id IS NULL, you are expressly requesting all rows that **didn't** have a matching record.  As for the ui.users_id = 2, you would just want to replace this with the appropriate users_id of interest when generating the query.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you randomize the sql so that so this is done in one query. I'm not sure if you are using mysql, tsql or something else but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412/how-to-request-a-random-row-in-sql) mentioned using `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1`. How about something like this:

```
select i.itemName
from users as s
left join items as i
    on i.id not in 
        (select ui.itemID from users_items as ui where ui.userID = u.id)
order by rand()
limit 1
```