# Please Solve this query - mysql

Tags: mysql

i have below table where i m storing question and multiple answers with id of quetion as below

```
table
ID Content QID
1  Q1      0
2  Q2      0
3  A1      1
4  A1      2
5  A2      1
6  A2      2
```

in above example Q for Question and A for Answer

Now i need result as question then its answer and so on e.g

I need output like First question and then all answer of that question.. then second question and all answers of that question...

```
1 Q1
3 A1
5 A2
2 Q2
4 A1
6 A2
```

Comment: I don't really understand what do you need. If you need to random order the rows, see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412/how-to-request-a-random-row-in-sql

Comment: I need output like First question and then all answer of that question.. then second question and all answers of that question...

Comment: Is this MySQL or SQL-Server?

Comment: MySql..  but sql server is also welcome

Comment: @Vucko Seriously? Couldn't understand the question?

Comment: @Kumar: The question is not that clear. Plus he's not explaining it with a lot of words...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one cheap solution (tested with MySQL):

```
SET @max_id = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM `table`);
SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY IF(QID > 0, @max_id * QID + ID, @max_id * ID)
```

It works only for one level of Questions/Answers. So if an answer can have sub-questions and sub-answers, this solution won't work for you. I'm sure there are better solutions.

If you want to run it in one query, you can do it like that:

```
SELECT * FROM `table`
ORDER BY IF(QID > 0,
  (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM `table`) * QID + ID,
  (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM `table`) * ID)
```

Comment: Thanks.. but when i test it is showing as Q1,Q2,A1,A2.. i need question then all answer and then next question and all answer of it

Comment: Maybe it's because of the @max_id variable. I have now added a second query, could you try that?

Comment: Yes but still same answer is in proper order but both question coming first..e.g. Q1,Q2...

Comment: Well I've tested it with your sample data and it worked. So I guess you're doing it with your real data. You probably have to modify the expression `QID > 0` - if your questions have a QID of 1 (in your sample they have 0) you have to write `QID > 1`.

Comment: Thanks a lot it is wroking...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I realy think this is a bad way of storing your data. 
Second, I even think it is a bad way of retrieving your data...

Anyway, I did not find a SQL statement for your result yet, but maybe this can help you:

```
SELECT question.ID as QuestionID, question.Content as Question, 
answer.ID as AnswerID, answer.Content as Answer 
FROM Test question, Test answer 
WHERE question.ID = answer.QID 
ORDER BY question.Content ASC
```

This should allow you to do what you want with the results... (Tested with SQL Server)