# Select a random row from a db

Tags: sql, database, hsqldb

I am looking for a solution which gives me a random row from a hsql db back.

```
CREATE TABLE Playlist(
    id INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
);
```

Any ideas?

UPDATE:

```
SELECT LIMIT 0 1 RAND(), p.name as foo
From Playlist p
ORDER BY foo
```

with this statement I get a random number back, but not a random playlist name.

Comment: Which RDBMS? What have you tried?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412/how-to-request-a-random-row-in-sql covers this

Comment: I can get back a random number but not a random element...

Comment: pls write it as an answer, so that I can except it. Thx for your solution!!!

Comment: write it below @PeterWooster `:D`

Comment: SO converted the short answer to a comment, it's now a bit longer as an answer.

Comment: @maximus, the answer has been posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should go to [How to request a random row in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412/how-to-request-a-random-row-in-sql)

It covers a quite a few options on how to do what you need.

```
SELECT p.name as foo
From Playlist p
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

If you are using Oracle, you need a subselect using Rownum instead of limit. see [How do I limit the number of rows returned by an Oracle query after ordering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470542/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-rows-returned-by-an-oracle-query-after-ordering)

Comment: Thanks @bonCodigo, Note that the limit works well in MySQL, but not in oracle, there it gets much uglier.

Comment: Forgot to add the link.. ;) http://viralpatel.net/blogs/fetch-random-rows-from-database-mysql-oracle-ms-sql-postgresql-example/