# How get random row?

Tags: sql, select, random

Good day.

```
SELECT * FROM banners WHERE seet='$seet'
```

Structure table `banners` here [**https://i.stack.imgur.com/KR6Xu.png**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KR6Xu.png)

Tell me please how get random one row from table?

Comment: Exact copy of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412/how-to-request-a-random-row-in-sql ?

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `SQL Server`? `MySQL`? `Oracle`? `DB2`? etc..

Answer (score 1):

SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [TableName] ORDER BY NEWID()

This assigns a GUID to each row, and will return a random record based on the TOP 1 and ORDER BY combined.