# Get 10 rows from a query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a query which consists of joins and has an output of about 30,000+ records. I would like to get 10 random rows from these records without using SQL command ORDER BY rand().

I tried looping through the records and put them in an array and shuffle (get the 1st 10 after shuffle) them but it takes about 8-12 seconds to generate. I would like to reduce this processing time at all cost.

How will I accomplish this?

Comment: And what's your current query?

Comment: And why don't you want to use rand()?

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible to get random rows from only the query without using rand. Are you using MySQL?

Comment: So - lets get this right - you want a "random" rows without using a function that generates random numbers. You can move the problem from SQL or to PHP or to ... Anyway you will have the same hurdle.

Comment: I did some searching -- http://stackoverflow.com/a/12852040/1814922 has some pretty intriguing answers. Haven't tried them though.

Comment: I tried popnoodles' method and cut off some 3-4 seconds generation time. I believe doing the random in PHP will give a better loading time compared to ORDER BY rand() in MYSQL.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok if you don't want to use RAND() do a much faster select of just the id column first then select only the 10 rows you want

1. Select the IDs into $idarray 

    `SELECT id FROM table`
2. Shuffle and slice $idarray 

    `shuffle($idarray);` 

     `$ids=array_slice($idarray,0,10);`
3. Select the complete rows

   `$sql="SELECT ... WHERE id IN (".implode(', ', $idarray).")";`

Edit: This is certainly much faster than using ORDER BY RAND()!

Comment: Fetching 30000+ IDs (and growing) from the database, shuffling them and then throwing away 29990+ of them will certainly be much slower than letting the RDBMS doing the randomizing...

Comment: I've just tested selecting that amount of IDs from a database and ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10 of *just the id column* takes 30+ times longer than without ORDER BY and LIMIT.

Comment: ... selecting 30 columns using ORDER BY and LIMIT takes over 1000 times longer. PHP takes 0.003 seconds to shuffle and slice 30,000 ids.

Comment: Thanks for you response. I tried your method and saved me 3-4 seconds generation time. This may sound silly but is there a method to just pick some rows in the MYSQL result without looping through the records one by one and also of course not using ORDER BY rand()?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. You have RAND() and LIMIT, unlike PHP there isn't usually more than one way to do something.

Comment: I think your idea is the best way for now. I try to improve my query so that the performance will improve too. Thanks for the help. Much appreciated.