# SQL: Get 2 rows from each category

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with different categories. Is it possible to return two random rows from each category?

**My table:**

```
-----------------------------
| ID | CATEGORY             |
-----------------------------
| 1  | PINK                 |
| 2  | GREEN                |
| 3  | PINK                 |
| 4  | GREEN                |
| 5  | BLUE                 |
| 6  | BLUE                 |
| 7  | BLUE                 |
| 8  | PINK                 |
| 9  | GREEN                |
-----------------------------
```

**What I want to output:**

```
-----------------------------
| ID | CATEGORY             |
-----------------------------
| 1  | PINK                 |
| 8  | PINK                 |
| 2  | GREEN                |
| 4  | GREEN                |
| 6  | BLUE                 |
| 7  | BLUE                 |
-----------------------------
```

Comment: Yes . it is possible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412/how-to-request-a-random-row-in-sql

Comment: ^that is a different question

Comment: The random part isnt as important. I was really looking for getting 2 rows from each category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select distinct c1.ID, c2.category
from mytable c1
join mytable c2 ON c1.category = c2.category and c1.ID <> c2.ID
group by c1.category, c2.ID;
```

Comment: This works, but lets say I want to get 5 rows from each category, would I have to join 5 tables?

Comment: You would need an additional self-join, and group by ID, for each increase in rows returned. For example, to get 3 of each category:

select distinct c1.ID, c2.category
from country c1
join country c2 ON c1.category = c2.category and c1.ID <> c2.ID
join country c3 ON c2.category = c3.category and c1.ID <> c3.ID
group by c1.category, c2.ID, c3.ID;

Comment: Hey there user2217162, either of these answers acceptable to you?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to get two random rows from each category:

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select t.category, substring_index(group_concat(id order by rand()), ',', 2) as ids
      from t
      group by category
     ) tc
     on find_in_set(t.id, tc.ids) > 0;
```

It uses `group_concat()` to put the ids into a list in random order, chooses the first two, and goes back and finds the rows with these ids.  It is easily generalizable to more than 2 ids.