# How select random column from mysql table?

Tags: mysql, database

My table is like this -

```
+---------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| PK      | ToicID        |topic1|topic2| topic3 |topic4 |
+---------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| 1       | 1             | abc  | xyz  | mno    | pqr   |
+---------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I use this query-

```
select * from table order by rand() limit 1
```

it's giving me only random row. But I want to select any topic random like following

```
Topic3
|mno|
```

==========================================

**But conditon is that column should't empty or null.**

Comment: is the number of topics fixed? (eg. 4)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to request a random column in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24858797/how-to-request-a-random-column-in-sql)

Comment: @etsa yes number of topic is fixed.

Comment: See probable duplicate question, but I want to add that the need for a random column indicates a design problem - consider redesigning the table. And don't butcher my edits :)

Comment: @fvu No, i check this post before its not my answer.

Comment: @fvu in your reference he is trying to get name from table i want just a random column it maybe topic1,topic3, topic2 any column randomly .

Comment: Seriously consider revising the design of your schema!

Comment: @Strawberry I had correct it :)

Comment: Any time you have enumerated columns, alarm bells should start ringing!

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks, Do you have any idea about my query??

Comment: Yeah, fix your data model. Anything else is just window dressing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pls can you check if this is what you are asking for?

```
SELECT  CASE FLOOR(RAND()*4+1)
             WHEN 1 THEN TOPIC1 
             WHEN 2 THEN TOPIC2 
             WHEN 3 THEN TOPIC3 
             WHEN 4 THEN TOPIC4 END AS TOPIC_RAND
FROM TABLE;
```

**Updated version after comments and added clause -NULL/blank in question:**

```
   select version() as 'mysql version';

SELECT  CASE FLOOR(RAND()*4+1)   /*wrote here just 1 to make tests */
    WHEN 1 THEN COALESCE(TOPIC1, TOPIC2, TOPIC3, TOPIC4)  
    WHEN 2 THEN COALESCE(TOPIC2, TOPIC3, TOPIC4, TOPIC1) 
    WHEN 3 THEN COALESCE(TOPIC3, TOPIC4, TOPIC1, TOPIC2) 
    WHEN 4 THEN COALESCE(TOPIC4, TOPIC1, TOPIC2, TOPIC3) END AS TOPIC_RAND
FROM (SELECT NULLIF(TOPIC1,'') AS TOPIC1, NULLIF(TOPIC2,'') AS TOPIC2,NULLIF(TOPIC3,'') AS TOPIC3,NULLIF(TOPIC4,'') AS TOPIC4          
      FROM TTE1) A;
```

Sample data

```
CREATE TABLE TTE1 (TOPIC1 VARCHAR(10), TOPIC2 VARCHAR(10), TOPIC3 VARCHAR(10), TOPIC4 VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO TTE1 VALUES ('abc','cde','efg','hij');
INSERT INTO TTE1 VALUES (NULL,'k2','k3','k4');
INSERT INTO TTE1 VALUES ('','i2','i3','i4');
```

Output:

```
mysql version
1   5.7.12-log

TOPIC_RAND
1   cde
2   k4
3   i2
```

Comment: I don't need if the column is blank or null, it should go to next one which has data. how will it do?

Comment: @Sunny    See COALESCE in the mean time...   Try to find solution by yourself... In a few minutes I'll update answer.  Let me know if you find solution by yourself

Comment: @ esta "Unexpected token" and "Unrecognized keyword." are errors.

Comment: I am working on rextester... Now I am posting output too for you.  Check if you wrote anything correctly...

Comment: Hi @etsa thank you for your answer, My mysql version is 5.1.73-community.
Is this reason for showing errors??

Comment: Try single things to see where you got error:  eg. try SELECT CASE WHEN 1=1 THEN 'One' ELSE 'Two' END, but I still think you misspelled something...

Answer (score 1):

A normalized schema might look like this (snippet):

```
topic_id topic_name 
       1 abc  
       2 xyz  
       3 mno  
       4 pqr
```

From here, the problem becomes trivial.