# How can I get particular Row in a query variable using ColdFusion?

Tags: coldfusion, cfquery

Take the following query example:

```
<cfquery name="Test" Datasource = "TestDB">
    Select * from Table_Test
</cfquery>
```

Assume that the "Test" query returns 10 rows. I want to show single row on current time.

Note: I do not want to change the SQL statement.

Comment: The sentence, "I want to show single row on current time.", is not clear.

Comment: I second what @DanBracuk says. I think CFML_Developer has answered your question, but that's predicated on guessing what you mean in that highlighted sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want one random row from the query:

```
    <cfset start = randRange(1, Test.recordCount)>
    <cfoutput>
        #Test.name[start]#&nbsp;#Test.email[start]#<br>
    </cfoutput>
```

No need to loop.

NOTE: It is more efficient to modify the query to get a random row.

[How to request a random row in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412/how-to-request-a-random-row-in-sql)

Comment: I'm not sure how you deduced that he wanted a random row, but kudos on taking that away from this question!

Comment: He had answered his question and it looked like that was what he was trying to do.  That answer has been removed so it now looks like I can read minds. ;)

Answer (score 7):

If you know your row number, `Test.columnName[RowNumber]` will show you the value of the columnName in specified row number.

Comment: Yes brother you are right.But the table has minimum 50 column any way Thank you for answering this question.