# Get an random String from MySQL with Java

Tags: java, mysql

I'm actually have the Problem that I don't know how to get a random 
nickname from my Table called "nicks" where the column called "nicknames".

Here is an example what I've.

```
private String getNames() {
    String names= "";
    try {
        ResultSet rs = Core.getSQL().getResultSet("SELECT * FROM nicks");

        names = rs.getString("nicknames");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return names;
  }
}
```

Can someone pls tell me why I only get the String "" and how I can get just one random entry out of my database?

Hope that someone can help me.

Comment: I'm surprised you're not just running into an Exception, considering you would need to point the `ResultSet` to a row before being able to pull any information. Or maybe you are and that is the reason you only receive an empty String

Comment: Saw that I'm getting an Error: java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set

Comment: In that case simply add an `rs.first()` or `rs.next()` and it should work.

Comment: Yeah, it is working now, but it isn't random. How can i randomize it ?

Comment: Like I said "I actually don't want to randomize it in the SQL Query. Could I randomize it in Java too ?"

Comment: Why would you want to do that though? It will be far less efficient as you will still retrieve all rows first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this Question: [How to request a random row in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412/how-to-request-a-random-row-in-sql)

In addition your try block should look something like this:

```
try {
    ResultSet rs = Core.getSQL().getResultSet("SELECT * FROM nicks");

    rs.next();
    names = rs.getString("nicknames");
}
```

Comment: I actually don't want to randomize it in the SQL Query. 
Could I randomize it in Java too ?

Comment: You could do it, but it will be more difficult and much less efficient.