# slick3: select random row

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I write application on scala and play framework with slick for db. I want to select random row from my table on db side. Something like this:

```
val items = TableQuery[ItemTable]
val db = Database.forConfig("db.default")

def getRandom: Item = ???
```

Any ideas? My current implementation is select all as list and chose random on scala code.

Comment: If you know maximum ID in your table, you could randomly select one with java `Random` and query `select * from something where id = rand`

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know rows count

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can defined custom function for slick 3.

Here is example:

```
  val randomFunction = SimpleFunction.nullary[Double]("rand")
  db.run(userTable.sortBy(x=>randomFunction).take(1).result
```

It generates next sql (for Slick 3.0.3):

```
select x2."field1", x2."field2" from (select x3."field1" as "field1", x3."field2" as "field2" from "Table" x3 order by rand() limit 1) x2
```

For Slick 3.1.0-RC1:

```
select x3."field1" as "field1", x3."field2" as "field2" from "Table" x3 order by rand() limit 1
```

But you should be aware that `"rand"` function is database specific.

Comment: thumbs up for `rand` being database specific

Comment: for postgresql use `random` instead of `rand`

Answer (score 0):

It's depends rather from the DB that you use than from Slick.

You need to use plain SQL, there is a good description fro the different databases in the answer to this question [How to request a random row in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412/how-to-request-a-random-row-in-sql)

Example for MySQL:

```
SELECT column FROM table
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```