# What exact code to be use in randomly retrieving items in mysql?

Tags: mysql, .net

I am trying to create an examination system, wherein i have databank in mysql. I would like to randomly select questions that will be display in the textbox.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to request a random row in SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412/how-to-request-a-random-row-in-sql)

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain a random row this way

```
SELECT * FROM Your_table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Well if my answer is what you are looking for please merk it as accepted ..