# Bookshelf - getting random entries from the database

Tags: bookshelf.js, knex.js

I've been digging Bookshelf documentation but I can't find enough information to get 5 random users from the database. Right now, the following code retrieves all users.

```
User.fetchAll().then((users) => {

});
```

However, is it possible to do something like this?

```
User.take(5).random().get().then((users) => {
    // random 5 users in users collection
});
```

I really don't want to write raw SQL but I'm fine doing it inside ORM using .query callbacks if necessary.

Comment: hi @Doge, which database are you using ?

Answer (score 3):

There's a [shuffle](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Collection-instance-shuffle) method in the included methods brought in from lodash.

```
User.shuffle().take(5).get().then((users) => {
    // random 5 users in users collection
});
```

Comment: I have around 100k entries on my database so I cannot rely on collection methods. It has to be done directly in the SQL.

Comment: That changes the question. You will have to drop into a raw query and use something from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412/how-to-request-a-random-row-in-sql