# Random strings SQL

Tags: c#, sql, random

I'm doing a chart using data into my database in a C# program. I have a list of users and i want to display in pseudo random order.

I've tried this code

```
void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Connessione.Open();
        MySqlDataAdapter SDA=new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT RAND() concorrente, id FROM Classifiche WHERE taglia='small' AND categoria='agility'",Connessione);
        DataTable DATA= new DataTable();
        SDA.Fill(DATA);
        dataGridView1.DataSource=DATA; 
        Connessione.Close();
    }
```

In this case, though, the query show me random numbers instead random strings. How can I fix it?

I've tried the solutions that was posted here [How to request a random row in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412/how-to-request-a-random-row-in-sql) but I can't resolve the problem

Comment: ORDER BY RAND() ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to request a random row in SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412/how-to-request-a-random-row-in-sql)

Comment: @Martheen now the program doesn't show me nothing

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `RAND()` if you use 'MySQL' database and `NEWID()` if you use 'Sql Server' in the `ORDER BY` clause of your query as following:

```
SELECT concorrente, id FROM Classifiche WHERE taglia='small' AND categoria='agility' ORDER BY RAND()
```

Comment: @Steve what can I use instead?

Comment: please debug your code, put a breakpoint after SDA.Fill(DATA) and check if DATA DataTable has any row. another thing: re-check if your WHERE clause has some matching result

Comment: @S.Serp the code works. If I don't use RAND() I can display my data, and I tried other conditions just to try and everytime the program runs well

Comment: can you edit your question with exactly the updated code you test now after adding `RAND()` function? please also add `MySQL` tag to its keywords

Answer (score 0):

Use the newid() instead

```
SELECT concorrente, id FROM Classifiche WHERE taglia='small' AND categoria='agility' ORDER BY newid()
```

Comment: No results :( Anyway I'm using Mysql, so RAND() theorically should be ok, but it isn't

Comment: @Marietto, tag your question with MySQL, to get MySQL answers!