# Selecting random balanced records based on two columns

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, record

[Sample Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iimEH.png)

I want to select 6 random records from this table based off 2 columns, the topic and the taxonomy.The selection of records must be balanced and repetition of topics and taxonomy should be kept a minimum.Is there an algorithm to do this?

Any help in either SQL or java would be appreciated.Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to request a random row in SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412/how-to-request-a-random-row-in-sql)

Comment: Please see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with an nth sample on an ordered set.  It is something like:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, (@rn := @rn + 1) as rn
      from t cross join
           (select @rn := 0) params
      order by topics, taxonomy
     ) t cross join
     (select count(*) as cnt from t) tt
where rn % floor(cnt / 6) = 1;
```

The idea is to use modulo arithmetic to take every nth value to get to 6.  You may have to fiddle with the exact parameters in the `where`, depending on the size of your data.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I think i can get it to work the way i expect it to with some tweaks to the where part.