# Get random data from SQL Server without performance impact

Tags: sql-server, random, sqlperformance

I need to select random rows from my sql table, when search this cases in google, they suggested to `ORDER BY NEWID()` but it reduces the performance. Since my table has more than 2'000'000 rows of data, this solution does not suit me.

I tried this code to get random data :

```
SELECT TOP 10 * 
FROM Table1
WHERE (ABS(CAST((BINARY_CHECKSUM(*) * RAND()) AS INT)) % 100) < 10
```

It also drops performance sometimes.

Could you please suggest good solution for getting random data from my table, I need minimum rows from that tables like 30 rows for each request. I tried **TableSAMPLE** to get the data, but it returns nothing once I added my where condition because it return the data by the basis of page not basis of row.

Comment: [Check this, I think this helps you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412/how-to-request-a-random-row-in-sql)

Comment: Does your table have a unique index or primary key?

Comment: Yes, it have primary key with unique index

Comment: your primary key is an identity?

Comment: @MtwStark No, it was uniqueIdentifier

Comment: I would suggest to move your primary key to an identity column and to keep your uniqueidentifier as alternate key. It will be very useful and you will see performances improvement in all conditions. Just consider that if your primary key is  `CLUSTERED` your new records will be inserted in the middle of the table and all the table reorganized. With identity PK your records will be appended to the tail.

Comment: @MtwStark I am okay with change my primary key as identity for performance improvement, could you please suggest some for your thoughts

Comment: you can look at my answer, it is appllyable both with identity and uniqueidentifier case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to calc the random ids before to filter your big table.
since your key is not identity, you need to number records and this will affect performances..

Pay attention, I have used distinct clause to be sure to get different numbers

**EDIT: I have modified the query to use an arbitrary filter on your big table**

```
declare @n int = 30

;with
t as (
    -- EXTRACT DATA AND NUMBER ROWS
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by YourPrimaryKey) n
    from YourBigTable t
    -- SOME FILTER
    WHERE 1=1  /* <-- PUT HERE YOUR COMPLEX FILTER LOGIC */
),
r as (
    -- RANDOM NUMBERS BETWEEN 1 AND COUNT(*) OF FILTERED TABLE
    select distinct top (@n) abs(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % n)+1  rnd
    from sysobjects s
    cross join (SELECT MAX(n) n FROM t) t
)
select t.*
from t
join r on r.rnd =  t.n
```

Comment: Since my table don't have id value for integer, i used Uniqueidentifier

Comment: Nice, is it good for big tables, Since my table has more than 2'000'000 rows

Comment: in my tests it is very very fast (250ms), also with uniqueidentifier as primarykey, and you can improve it much more replacing the `COUNT(*)` for `@max` with a more efficient function and get ~30% less

Comment: Its really nice, number will generate by the basis of @max values, in my case i add some where conditions for pick the data, so i need to duplicate this condition get max count and random pick, Is there any other way to avoid this

Comment: how many rows you have after the where condition? 1'000, 100K, 500K, 1M, 1.8M?

Comment: I will get 100k rows after the where condition and one more think, above code rare to pick first and second row.

Comment: for where condition, check new version.. and, what you mean about picking 1st and 2nd row?

Comment: Hey, it was great. I will check your code against my table. My question was its pick random data, consider my row numbers are sequence from 1 to 100. In the above code pick random rows. its fine. i executed more 50 times this query but i never seen my 1st row and 2nd row, it picks mostly row number 10 or more

Comment: this is normal, they calls it Gaussian Distribution, it is very difficult to pick boundaries when you pick 30 numbers out of 2mil rows (or 100k rows) also, be sure your where condition filter include them or you'll never get them! :)

Answer (score -1):

If your uniqueidentifier key is a random GUID (not generated with NEWSEQUENTIALID() or UuidCreateSequential), you can use the method below. This will use the clustered primary key index without sorting all rows.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM (VALUES(
      NEWID()),(NEWID()),(NEWID()),(NEWID()),(NEWID()),(NEWID()),(NEWID()),(NEWID()),(NEWID()),(NEWID())
    ,(NEWID()),(NEWID()),(NEWID()),(NEWID()),(NEWID()),(NEWID()),(NEWID()),(NEWID()),(NEWID()),(NEWID())
    ,(NEWID()),(NEWID()),(NEWID()),(NEWID()),(NEWID()),(NEWID()),(NEWID()),(NEWID()),(NEWID()),(NEWID())) AS ThirtyKeys(ID)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT TOP (1) * FROM dbo.Table1 WHERE ID >= ThirtyKeys.ID) AS t1;
```

Comment: Hey my primary key was new sequentialId

Comment: you can extract 30 times the same record

Comment: and also you can get less than 30 records