# Generating unique random number as identification in database

Tags: c#, sql-server, random

I have been making ID in my program but to have one it need to generate random numbers but if it already exist in my database then it has to perform another random numbers to prevent duplication . My problem is how do i generate another random numbers again?

here's my code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       random rand = new random();
        aidentification.Text = rand.Next(1, 5).ToString();   
        string exist = string.Empty;
        exist =  "Select * from fruit_stock " +
                  "where identification=@id";



        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("server=WIN10;database=fruit_storage;user=fruit_admin;password=admin;");

       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand()
    {
        Connection = conn,
        CommandType = CommandType.Text,
        CommandText = exist

    };
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", aidentification.Text);
        try
        {
         conn.Open();
         SqlDataReader reader;
         reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.HasRows){
               // PUT THE CODE HERE TO PERFORM ANOTHER RANDOM NUMBERS
            }
         conn.Close();
        }
      catch (Exception ex) {
          MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
      }

    }      
}
```

}

Comment: Why not make the SQL portion a function that determines if ID has rows, and returns has or has not, then you can just { pick number } while (has rows)

Comment: better way you mark the `identification` column as primary key and then do some code changes in your code for whenever you try to insert record with same id then this will throw the exception

Comment: Why not declare an `ID int IDENTITY ` column on your table - that way it will autogenerate the ID for you and you need no guessing. This approach of guessing a free, new ID has so many problems that I wont even start. [msdn, IDENTITY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775(v=sql.110).aspx)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to request a random row in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412/how-to-request-a-random-row-in-sql)

Answer (score 1):

This answer is about not having your problem - not solving it in code (fix by better design)

```
CREATE TABLE fruitInStock
(
 id int IDENTITY(1,1),
 fruitname varchar (20), -- this should be a FK into a fruits table 
 amountOf int NOT NULL
  -- more fields
);    

INSERT fruitInStock
   (fruitname , amountOf )
VALUES
   ('Apple', 20),
   ('Pear', 10),
   ('Kiwi', 2000)    
;

SELECT * from fruitInStock
```

gives

```
id  fruitname   amountOf
1   Apple   20
2   Pear    10
3   Kiwi    2000
```

The ID is autogenerated on insert and wont ever duplicate - the database takes care of its own integrity and your code does not have to. Simply insert without ID.

Comment: I have done that but the task given to me is use a random class in ID

Comment: @Ndrangheta If you need to get one random row from your table which is filled with data, use this SO answers suggestion:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/19419/7505395

Comment: @MethodMan  'INTO' can be omitted - and instead of trying to get one over and over one could simply get a random one with one try: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19419/7505395

Comment: @PatrickArtner how does this link help.. Random Row and Random Number are not the same

Comment: the random class must be on the c# code and not in the sql query

Comment: @MethodMan He is computing a random number, is setting it to some Textbox-Input element, then he is checking if this number exists in his table, then he wants to get another random number and so forth. He is drawing random results from his table - the linked answer will allow him to do this: drawing one (or more if he changes the TOP clause) random rows from his data.

Comment: @Ndrangheta: Please revisit your questions and put **all sideconditions** into it. I am under the impression this is _again_ one of those "homework with unreasonable side condition" tasks ...

Answer (score 1):

You Try This

```
DECLARE @ID INT ,@New_ID INT
IF EXISTS(Select 1 from fruit_stock where identification=@id)
     SET @New_ID=MAX(identification)+1 FROM fruit_stock -- It Will give you Random Number
```

OR

```
DECLARE @ID INT ,@New_ID INT
IF EXISTS(Select 1 from fruit_stock where identification=@id)
     SET @New_ID=ABS(CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY) AS INT))-- It Will give you Random Number
```

Comment: the first will give the next id for that table  by calculating the max and adding ,  the second one a huge one based on a guid's int value. The second one is at least a bit rand-ish

Answer (score 0):

If you need to generate the identifier on the client side (can be necessary in distributed systems, when the access to the central database is not always reliably available), you could just use a `Guid` instead of an `int` as your primary identifier. Generate it locally with `Guid.NewGuid()`, and with Microsoft databases you can define the type of the column in the table as `Guid`.

Comment: i like guid but its generating really really long output. I only want to generate 5 or 8 digits