# Random pick from a Table using RAND() does not work properly

Tags: mysql

I created a table consists of two columns, `id` and `name`.

```
create table City(id integer, name varchar(100));
insert into City(id, name) values (1, "Jakarta"), (2, "Bandung"), (3, "Tangerang"), (4, "Depok"), 
(5, "Surabaya"), (6, "Lampung"), (7, "Balikpapan"), (8, "Bogor");
```

I would like to pick a row randomly via the `id`. The code `select floor(rand()*8) + 1` works fine. It does give random integers from 1 to 8.

The line

```
select * from City where id = floor(rand()*8) + 1
```

should always return one row only from `City`. But when I tried, it sometimes return more than one row, or even none. Why is this? thanks.

Comment: duplication please see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412/how-to-request-a-random-row-in-sql

Answer (score 0):

Since you only have 8 cities in your table, you can just do:

```
select *
from City
order by rand()
limit 1
```