# MYSQL pickup Random row after order by

Tags: php, mysql

I want to pick a random row after doing an order by.

My result can sometime return 2 rows with same value. So what i want to do it that i want to select 1 row randomtly between the same rows returned.

In the below example i want to return 1 row between the 2 same rows returned.

Thanks.

```
select nondox, account, id 
    from rates2 where weight='32' and country_code='US' 
         and service like '%INT%' 
    order by nondox,account
```

Result of the above query is

```
nondox  account   id 
276.16  610661731 25805209
276.16  610798714 2108989
391.68  610662766 1281799
```

Comment: Why not just using `ORDER BY RAND()....LIMIT 1` in your sql?

Comment: `ORDER BY nondox, account, RAND() LIMIT 1`

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19419/10732434). It's for more database systems but [tag:mysql] is listed first.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to request a random row in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412/how-to-request-a-random-row-in-sql)

Comment: ORDER BY RAND()....LIMIT 1 will not select the cheapest nondox value

Answer (score 0):

Can provide more details ?
This will eliminate the similar nondox values it's not completely random but it should work.
 `select account, id , nondox from rates2 where weight='32' and country_code='US' and service like '%INT%' group by nondox order by nondox,account`

Comment: your code will always select the 2nd row. I want to cycle between 1st and 2nd rows

Answer (score 0):

you can use function RAND() that generates a random value for each row in the table

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1;
```

for more informations checkout this [link](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/select-random-records-database-table.aspx/)

Comment: If I order by rand() then how can I make sure the cheapest nondox value is at the top?

Comment: you can use Min function min(nondox)

Answer (score -2):

you can put the result in an array, then create a random integer with random(with limit) the output the values of the index from random.
example random outputs 2, you return array[random+1] ie array[3]