# How can I return a random row for each section in a MySQL data set that has non-unique values

Tags: mysql, sql

#### Given the dataset

```
+-----------+---------+
| device_id | section |
+-----------+---------+
| 100       | A       |
+-----------+---------+
| 101       | B       |
+-----------+---------+
| 102       | B       |
+-----------+---------+
| 103       | C       |
+-----------+---------+
| 104       | D       |
+-----------+---------+
| 105       | C       |
+-----------+---------+
| 106       | A       |
+-----------+---------+
| 107       | C       |
+-----------+---------+
```

What MySQL query will produce one (and only one) row for each section, selected at random.

#### Expected results (random variation):

```
+-----------+---------+
| device_id | section |
+-----------+---------+
| 106       | A       |
+-----------+---------+
| 101       | B       |
+-----------+---------+
| 105       | C       |
+-----------+---------+
| 104       | D       |
+-----------+---------+
```

I have tried several variations using `GROUP BY` and `DISTINCT` but have not had any success.

--edit-- I updated the title to clarify that I am **not** asking that a single row be returned, but that I get one, and only one `device_id` for each distinct section.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to request a random row in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412/how-to-request-a-random-row-in-sql)

Comment: @Progman no -- I don't need a single random row, I need one random row for *each* section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `group_concat()` to create a comma separated list of all the `device_id`s of each `section` in random order and pick the 1st with `substring_index()`:

```
select substring_index(group_concat(device_id order by rand()), ',', 1) device_id,
       section
from tablename
group by section
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=dd6f69176e6ae6a534d1f8c1e155241e).

For MySql 8.0+ you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
select device_id, section
from (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by section order by rand()) rn
  from tablename
) t
where rn = 1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2f05e3fbf4e5203ef60fb131a22c8dd2).

Comment: Thank you. I am using MySQL 8, but the first solution seems cleaner and more intuitive.