# PHP - Select random row from table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

My table has around 10k rows. How can I query select 1 random row of the last 10 added rows? I have a date column that is datetime of when the row was added.

This is one I use to get the last 10 rows:

```
SELECT id FROM mytable order by date desc LIMIT 10
```

I know I can do `SELECT id FROM mytable ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1` but that just choose any random row, not from the last 10 rows.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Have not any `id` in your table

Comment: Write the query that gets the last 10 added records, and then use that as a sub-query in a query that randomly orders the results and applies a limit of 1.

Comment: try `ORDER BY RAND()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to request a random row in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412/how-to-request-a-random-row-in-sql)

Comment: @BenM Sorry, updated!

Comment: @Cindy . . . Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Done! PhpMyAdmin

Comment: @Cindy . . . PhpMyAdmin is a GUI interface.  Presumably the database is MySQL.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Oh ok, Yes, MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method uses a subquery:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT id
      FROM mytable 
      ORDER BY date DESC
      LIMIT 10
     ) t
ORDER BY rand()
LIMIT 1;
```

This version uses the syntax conventions for MySQL.

You can use `select *` in the subquery to fetch the whole row.